# interpolate a variale to variable in jenkins pipeline(groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Hi I am now working on jenkins pipepline, in my build stage, I run gradle task

```
        stage('Build') {
            echo 'Building..'

            try {
                timeout(time: config.application.buildTimeoutMinutes, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                    Closure buildTask = {
                        runGradleTasks(config.application.gradleTasks.lab, GRADLE, config.credentials)
                    }

                    buildTask()
                }
            } catch (e) {
                echo "Failed build and test step ${e}"
                throw e
            }
        }
```

and the runGradleTasks is:

```
void runGradleTasks(String tasks, String gradle, credentials) {
    timeout(time: 20, unit: 'MINUTES') {
        if (credentials.something) {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${credentials.something}", usernameVariable: 'SOME_USER', passwordVariable: 'SOME_KEY')]) {
                sh("${gradle} -PartifactoryUser=${SOME_USER} -PartifactoryKey=${SOME_KEY} ${tasks}")
            }
        } else {
            sh("${gradle} ${tasks}")
        }
    }
}
```

it just run some like  `gradle clean build`.

I also have a configuration file(.yml):

```
application:
  gradleTasks:
    lab: clean buildLab prepareDeployment
    prod: clean build prepareDeployment
```

this is used for `config.application.gradleTasks.lab`.

It works well so far

But you may see for different environment, I run different gradle tasks.  then I defined userInput.env(let user to input env)

and do this

```
        stage('Build') {
            echo 'Building..'

            try {
                timeout(time: config.application.buildTimeoutMinutes, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                    Closure buildTask = {
                        runGradleTasks(config.application.gradleTasks.${userInput.env}, GRADLE, config.credentials)
                    }

                    buildTask()
                }
            } catch (e) {
                echo "Failed build and test step ${e}"
                throw e
            }
        }
```

It will throw error saying:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified method java.util.LinkedHashMap $ org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:113)
```

I know this is caused by `config.application.gradleTasks.${userInput.env}`.

How to fix this? I mean, how to interpolate a varible into a varible(defined in config yaml file) and also put it as parameters for the function `runGradleTasks`